# Reading from a txt file (C++)?

Tags: c++, filestream

When use ifstream to read from a txt file into 2d array i get some extra chars.

Txt file:
[image]

I get:

[image]
**My code:**

```
ifstream read;
read.open(resourcePath() + "res/txt/menu.txt");
if (read.fail()) {
    read.close();
    cout << "File does not exist!" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT/BLOCK_HEIGHT; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH/BLOCK_WIDTH; j++) {
        read >> board[i][j];
    }
}

read.close();
```

Could someone point out the mistake?

Comment: It's a 16x12 board both times, are you sure you are reading the proper file?

Comment: @ratchetfreak yes, i am sure.

Comment: This is a general C++ programming question which is not specific to game development. That means it should rather be posted on stackoverflow.com. When you repost there, please also show what the types and values of the variables `HEIGHT`, `WIDTH`, `BLOCK_HEIGHT` and `BLOCK_WIDTH` are and how exactly you allocated the memory for the `board` array.

Comment: Show the whole code. including array declaration

Comment: The question got reposted and answered on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38585425/how-to-read-a-grid-from-a-file-into-2-dimensional-array-in-c Please vote to close.

Answer (score 0):

```
read >> board[i][j];
```

looks wrong. Try to read only one char or use string manipulation afterwards to extract the Boolean type.